# I would like to set up a ubuntu OS on Amazon web server, how do I do this

Tags: aws

I am trying to set up a virtual OS (ubuntu, windows) on amazon web services to run apps 24/7 and to have anytime I log in on the internet. Is this a possibility to do and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose one of [preconfigured AMIs](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#os) on your Amazon EC2 instance. There is one with Ubuntu Server 11.04 inside: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B007IJK9FM/ref=%20mkt_ste_ec2

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a virtual machine running any of several operating systems is certainly possible in Amazon Web Services.  The [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) service is specifically built for this purpose.  There is an introductory video on the linked page, it tells the story.

Documentation for AWS EC2 provides step by step instructions for setting up a virtual machine running any one of several Linux distros or various flavors of the MS Windows OS.  The process is described [here](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/getting-started/).